# Poetry build without .env file?

Tags: python, python-poetry

Using Poetry as my Python dependency manager, I build libraries I then use in other Python projects.

I noticed, when pulling my custom libs,  the *.env* presence in my built libs. As they contain sensitive informations, I don't want them to be uploaded to my repository manager.

Is there a clean way to build a Python package while ignoring the *.env* ? It's location may depend on each lib.

To date, my only workaround is to manually remove the *.env*. Build & Publish. Then rolling back my *.env*.

Comment: Do you use *git* for these projects? -- Also did you read this? https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#include-and-exclude

Comment: Nope. Many thanks ! It almost fulfill my objective as I don't know .env location or exact names for each project.

Comment: You can tell Poetry to ignore all `.env` files. Simple and straightforward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I highly recommend to put the `.env` into the root folder of your project. It is not part of your actual package.

The benefit of putting it into the root folder is, that it will not be included in the `sdist` or `wheel` file by default.

As for any programming project I further recommend to use `git` for your project. If you put `.env` in your `.gitignore` file, Poetry will not include it into a package build as well.

Comment: I wasn't ignoring my .env files with .gitignore. I was using git without adding them. It fixed my issue, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I ended up making a bash script. It first check if you execute it at the root project, move all .env* to ., build, move back all .env* to initial location and push.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Check if correct execution path
cando=$(ls pyproject.toml)
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
  echo "Wrong execution path"
  exit
fi

# List all .env*
mapfile -t env_paths < <( find . -name ".env*" -not -path "./.venv/*" )

# Move found .env to .
echo "Temporarly del all .env*"
for env in ${env_paths[@]}; do
  mv ${env} .
done

# Poetry stuff
echo "Building package"
poetry build

# List all moved .en*
mapfile -t rollback_paths < <( find . -name ".env*" -not -path "./.venv/*" )
arraylength=${#rollback_paths[@]}

# Move .env to initial location
echo "Moving back all .env*"
for (( i=0; i<${arraylength}; i++ )); do
  mv ${rollback_paths[i]} ${env_paths[i]}
done

# Poetry stuff
echo "Pushing package"
poetry publish -r <my-repo>
v=$(poetry version)
echo "Pushed ${v}"
```